# Python Zeep Error requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, zeep

I am trying to do a request using zeep to SOAP Webservice (WSDL) But I don't know why I get this error. The Webservice is working using SOAP UI. I think I don't pass in the correct way the parameters in python, but I researched in the Zeep documentation that this is correct, I tested it in Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10, the same error in both.

WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:intf="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com" xmlns:tns1="http://dto.infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Oct 06, 2010 (02:39:27 GMT)-->
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://dto.infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com">
   <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
   <complexType name="ParametrosConsultaDTO">
    <sequence>
     <element name="codigoInformacion" nillable="true" type="soapenc:string"/>
     <element name="motivoConsulta" nillable="true" type="soapenc:string"/>
     <element name="numeroIdentificacion" nillable="true" type="soapenc:string"/>
     <element name="tipoIdentificacion" nillable="true" type="soapenc:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>

     <message name="consultaXmlRequest">

      <part name="in0" type="tns1:ParametrosConsultaDTO"/>

     </message>

     <message name="consultaXmlResponse">

      <part name="consultaXmlReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>

     </message>

     <message name="consultaPlanoRequest">

      <part name="in0" type="tns1:ParametrosConsultaDTO"/>

     </message>

     <message name="consultaPlanoResponse">

      <part name="consultaPlanoReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>

     </message>

     <message name="cambioPasswordRequest">

      <part name="in0" type="soapenc:string"/>

     </message>

     <message name="cambioPasswordResponse">

      <part name="cambioPasswordReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>

     </message>

     <portType name="InformacionComercialWS">

      <operation name="consultaXml" parameterOrder="in0">

           <input name="consultaXmlRequest" message="intf:consultaXmlRequest"/>

           <output name="consultaXmlResponse" message="intf:consultaXmlResponse"/>

      </operation>

      <operation name="consultaPlano" parameterOrder="in0">

           <input name="consultaPlanoRequest" message="intf:consultaPlanoRequest"/>

           <output name="consultaPlanoResponse" message="intf:consultaPlanoResponse"/>

      </operation>

      <operation name="cambioPassword" parameterOrder="in0">

           <input name="cambioPasswordRequest" message="intf:cambioPasswordRequest"/>

           <output name="cambioPasswordResponse" message="intf:cambioPasswordResponse"/>

      </operation>

     </portType>

     <binding name="InformacionComercialSoapBinding" type="intf:InformacionComercialWS">

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <operation name="consultaXml">

           <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

           <input name="consultaXmlRequest">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>

           </input>

           <output name="consultaXmlResponse">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>

           </output>

      </operation>

      <operation name="consultaPlano">

           <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

           <input name="consultaPlanoRequest">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>

           </input>

           <output name="consultaPlanoResponse">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>

           </output>

      </operation>

      <operation name="cambioPassword">

           <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

           <input name="cambioPasswordRequest">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>

           </input>

           <output name="cambioPasswordResponse">

                <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>

           </output>

      </operation>

     </binding>

     <service name="InformacionComercialWSService">

      <port name="InformacionComercial" binding="intf:InformacionComercialSoapBinding">

           <wsdlsoap:address location="https://ttuweb3.universo.corp/InformacionComercialWS/services/InformacionComercial"/>

      </port>

     </service>

</definitions>
```

Request using SOAP UI:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:inf="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <inf:consultaXml soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <in0 xsi:type="dto:ParametrosConsultaDTO" xmlns:dto="http://dto.infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com">
        <codigoInformacion xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">1401</codigoInformacion>
        <motivoConsulta xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">24</motivoConsulta>
        <numeroIdentificacion xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">80775779</numeroIdentificacion>
        <tipoIdentificacion xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">1</tipoIdentificacion>
     </in0>
      </inf:consultaXml>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My python code:

```
import requests
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  # or HTTPDigestAuth, or OAuth1, etc.
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep import xsd
from zeep.plugins import HistoryPlugin
from zeep.xsd import ComplexType
from lxml import etree

end_point= 'https://cifinpruebas.asobancaria.com/InformacionComercialWS/services/InformacionComercial?wsdl'
session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth("username", "password")
session.cert='certificate.pem'
soap_client = Client(end_point,
transport=Transport(session=session,timeout=60), service_name="InformacionComercialWSService", port_name="InformacionComercial")
parametros_consulta_dto = soap_client.get_type('ns0:ParametrosConsultaDTO')
parameters = parametros_consulta_dto(codigoInformacion="1401", motivoConsulta="24", numeroIdentificacion="80775779",
tipoIdentificacion="1")
soap_client.service.consultaXml(parameters)
```

Error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ttuweb3.universo.corp', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /InformacionComercialWS/services/InformacionComercial (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f8e7d3d3af0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

I have been spend several days to find a solution but without results. Thanks.

**edit 1: Image of SOAP UI response**

[image: expected response]

**edit 2: Image of SOAP UI Information about endpoint**

[image: endpoint information]

Additionally I tested the generated XML as this guide [reporting_bugs](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/reporting_bugs.html), and I used it in SOAP UI, it works, I don't have problems with the parameters, probably in the SSL authentication.

**edit 3: Change the code for only use requests library.**
Hi, I decided to test the soap request just using requests library (maybe zeep could failed in the authentication), but I convinced that it was a server error from the webservice provider.

```
    import requests
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

cert_file="path to cert"
key_file="path to key"

endpoint='https://cifinpruebas.asobancaria.com/InformacionComercialWS/services/InformacionComercial?wsdl'
session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth("user", "password")

body = """<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:inf="http://infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <inf:consultaXml soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <in0 xsi:type="dto:ParametrosConsultaDTO" xmlns:dto="http://dto.infocomercial.cifin.asobancaria.com">
            <codigoInformacion xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">1401</codigoInformacion>
            <motivoConsulta xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">24</motivoConsulta>
            <numeroIdentificacion xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">80775779</numeroIdentificacion>
            <tipoIdentificacion xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">1</tipoIdentificacion>
        </in0>
    </inf:consultaXml>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"""

body = body.encode('utf-8')
session.headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"}
session.headers.update({"Content-Length": str(len(body))})
response = session.post(url=endpoint, data=body, cert=(cert_file, key_file))
print(response)
```

I was using the RSA PRIVATE KEY and the Certificate, but in the response I got the following error:

```
    <Response [500]>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>  
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode
                xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction
            </faultcode>   
            <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>  
            <detail>
                <ns2:hostname
                    xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ttuweb3
                </ns2:hostname>  
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So it is a server error, but I'm so confused as I said that the request is working using SOAP UI. Any explanation about it?

Comment: DNS problem: the hostname `ttuweb3.universo.corp` can not be resolved.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: The hostname is not valid in the public domain system. There must be something internal in the local DNS. The best source for help should be the person responsible for the network or the server you are connecting to.

Comment: I think it is valid because I'm using the same endpoint in soap ui, let me update the post adding the image of the soap ui response.

Comment: I just update, please look the url of the request

Comment: That URL is not relevant. Have a look at the port URL near the end of the WSDL document.

Comment: ok, you're right, but I have to find a way to do it, because I don't understand why from the SOAP UI it works, and from code it doesn't.